# Getting a form's submit URL as a relative url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a form located at:

```
http://www.mysite.com/some/place/some/where/index.php
```

And I have this form:

```
<form action="submit.php"> ... </form>
```

If I do this:

```
$("form").attr("action");
```

I will get:

```
submit.php
```

What is a foolproof way to get the action from the form, so that it includes the entire URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com/some/place/some/where/submit.php
```

?

Comment: `$("form").attr("action");` this will give you `submit.php` not `index.php`

Comment: X-Y problem. Why do you *need* the full URL? It shouldn't matter for anything you can do with JavaScript.

Comment: Note: What you want to get is called an "absolute" URL.  The "relative" URL is what you have in the form.

Comment: window.location.href ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$("form").prop("action");
```

or (assuming your form is in the same folder as the page and the page URL ends with /something)

```
var loc = location.href;
var page = loc.substring(0,loc.lastIndexOf("/")+1)+
  $("form").attr("action");
```

Handle query strings and hashes especially for Quentin:

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/t8mdq/)

```
var loc = location.origin + location.pathname;
var action = $("form").attr("action").split("/").pop();
var page = loc.substring(0,loc.lastIndexOf("/"))+"/"+action;
```

Comment: Best answer I've seen so far, but it will break if the form's action starts with `/` or is absolute.

Comment: @Quentin sure, but if it starts with / then it is in the root and not in the same folder as /some/place/some/where/index.php

Comment: Exactly, but this code will concatenate it with the current URL regardless so the `/` of the relative URI won't be appended to the root of the current URL but to the whole current url (before the last `/`).

Comment: Oh, it will also break if the query string of the current URL includes a `/` character (since the query is part of `location.href`).

Comment: Why would `action="/foo"` on `http://example.com/bar/` being converted to `http://example.com/bar//foo` be desirable?

Comment: It would not, but according to OP, the action="submit.php" in a page that is http://www.server.com/folder/folder/folder/index.php

Comment: Well yes, and it works for standard relative URIs, so it works for the specific example in the question. It isn't robust enough to handle any URI that might be there though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.createElement('a');
el.href = $("form").prop("action");

alert(el.href);
```

Chrome adjusts the href to give the absolute url, not sure with other browsers